# Ruby installation on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, bundler

I've installed rvm and ruby. When I type *rvm list* I get this:

```
$ rvm rubies
=* ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

But when I try to use bundle I get something like this:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0
```

I don't know why bundler and rake try to use a different ruby version. How to can I fix it?? I'm using the latest Ubuntu version. Thanks for all replies ;)

Edit:
It is very strange. I reopened my terminal. Now when I try to list rubies with [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) I get:

```
$ rvm list
The program 'rvm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install ruby-rvm
```

And:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

Edit2:
Sorry for the lame question but I'm new in ruby and linux so...:)

Edit3:
Ok, now I know what the problem is. I've tried to use rvm and bundle as the root user. When I'm on the custom user everything works. So lame ;) Can I use rvm on root account or isn't this a good operation?

Comment: What is your system Ruby version?  You don't state that you do a `rvm use 2.1.0` before your `rvm rubies` command.  Show your steps, we may be able to help.

Comment: I think your bundler gem is installed with system ruby - 1.9.3.